# java.lang.IllegalStateException occur while running below code

Tags: android

When I Run the following code, the application is crashing

```
private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {

    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Create login session
                    session.setLogin(true);

                    // Launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // Error in login. Get the error message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("tag", "login");
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

here is the logcat response while crash

```
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.security.amr.isk, PID: 20940
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3858)
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4473)
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18472)
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3853)
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4473) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18472) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.security.amr.isk.LoginActivity.checkLogin(LoginActivity.java:202)
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.security.amr.isk.LoginActivity.Login(LoginActivity.java:127)
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3853) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4473) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18472) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what code is in line 202?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your logcat it says

`<i>java.lang.NullPointerException 10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/?<i>
      E/AndroidRuntime: at
      com.security.amr.isk.LoginActivity.checkLogin(LoginActivity.java:202) 
      10-08 14:20:41.853 20940-20940/? 
      E/AndroidRuntime: at
      com.security.amr.isk.LoginActivity.Login(LoginActivity.java:127)`

from here we can say you have a variable that is not assigned yet.check your login method or oncreate to see if you forgot to initialize a variable.for more information i need to see more code mate.

Comment: error in this line 
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
i replace it by used
 Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(strReq);
thx for help